# Algorithm design for competition management software

Tags: algorithm

I am designing a basic piece of software to manage sporting competitions.
Each competitor (C) competes 3 times, however the competition is staggered such that it goes:

C1 Run 1

C1 Run 2

C2 Run 1

C1 Run 3

C2 Run 2

C3 Run 1

C2 Run 3

C3 Run 2

C4 Run 1

etc.

I would rather not have to hard code in this sequence, is there a way I could create an algorithm which would output the competitor sequence as an array (In this case it would be [1,1,2,1,2,3,2,3,4...])
I have tried using nested for loops but can't seem to get it to output even close to what I need.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you break up the sequence into: `[1] [1 2 1] [2 3 2][3 4 3][4 5 4] ...` and maybe a special case for the final number?

Comment: Could you define the sequence more clearly?  With the current question, we can only try to guess what you want.  Also, maybe show your code?